Determinant of Nonzero Minor Of The Matrix
I recently started learning differential geometry from Lectures on the Geometry of Manifolds
written by Nicolaescu (this is a link to it: https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf). When I am reading the proof about the level set of manifold is a manifold at page 22 of the pdf file, I encountered some issues.
The proposition is the following:
Let M be a smooth manifold of dimension m and $f_1, . . . , f_k\in C^∞(M)$.
Define
\begin{equation*}
Z = Z(f_1, . . . , f_k) = \{p ∈ M; f_1(p) = · · · = f_k(p) = 0 \}.
\end{equation*}
Assume that the functions $f_1, . . . , f_k$ are functionally independent along Z, i.e., for each $p ∈ Z$,
there exist local coordinates $(x_
1
, . . . , x_m)$ defined in a neighborhood of p in M such that $x_
i
(p) =
0, i = 1, . . . , m$, and the matrix
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_p=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}&...&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_m}\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_1}&...&\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_m}
\end{pmatrix}_{x_1=x_2=...=x_m=0}
\end{equation*}
has rank k. Then Z has a natural structure of smooth manifold of dimension m − k.
In the proof, the author defines
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_p=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}&...&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_m}\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_1}&...&\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_m}
\end{pmatrix}_{x_1=x_2=...=x_m=0}
\end{equation*} and \begin{equation*} x'=(x_1,...,x_{m-k})\end{equation*}\begin{equation*} x''=(x_{m-k+1},...,x_{m})\end{equation*}\begin{equation*} F:\mathbb{R}^{m-k}\times\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k\end{equation*} given by\begin{equation*}
x\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}f_1(x)\\\vdots\\f_k(x)\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^k\end{equation*}
Then the author claims \begin{equation*} DF_2=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x''}:\mathbb{R}^{k}\times\mathbb{R}^k\end{equation*} is invertible since its determinant corresponds to our
nonzero minor.
My question is about this claim, why can we claim the determinant is not 0 from the minor is not 0?

You need to ensure that the last $k$ columns of $Df(p) = DF(p)$ form an invertible matrix. From the assumption all you can deduce is that some $k$ columns are linearly independent. To make these the last $k$ columns, you have to permute the coordinates.

thank you so much for your help! I did not notice the assumption about that f1 to k are functionally independent.
